# Get Branches of Code from Specific Team Project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I'm trying to get a list of code branches in TFS via code, but only those under a specific Team Project.  The code I'm currently using gives me back all branches, from all Team projects, whether they are active or deleted.

How can I filter the results to only bring back results from the Team Project I'm specifically after?

```
        List<string> listOfBranches = new List<string>();
        TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(@"MyTFSCollection"));
        VersionControlServer vcs = (VersionControlServer)tpc.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

        var allProjects = tpc.GetService(typeof(TeamProject));

        var branchObjects = vcs.QueryRootBranchObjects(RecursionType.Full);

        foreach (var branch in branchObjects)
        {
            var branchName = branch.Properties.RootItem.Item;
            var parentFolder = branchName.Substring(0, branchName.LastIndexOf('/'));

            listOfBranches.Add(branchName);
        }
        listOfBranches.Sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not able to branches under a specific team project with SOAP api. You have to use [REST API with `scopePath` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/tfvc/branches/get%20branch%20refs?view=vsts-rest-4.1):

```
Get http://TFS2015:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/teamproject/_apis/tfvc/branches?scopePath=&/teamproject&api-version=2.2
```